# SonarQube is not starting

Tags: sonarqube

I installed SonarQube 6.5 on my Debian Jessie server, I configured the MySQL database, configured `conf/sonar.properties` file according to https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing+the+Server, tried to start it with the `/opt/sonarqube/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh start` command, but it does not start.

These are the only lines of logs I see into `/opt/sonarqube/logs/sonar.log`:

```
--> Wrapper Started as Daemon
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

2017.10.16 21:43:05 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /opt/sonarqube/temp
2017.10.16 21:43:05 INFO  app[][o.s.a.p.JavaProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[es]: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djna.nosys=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonarqube/temp -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/search/* org.sonar.search.SearchServer /opt/sonarqube/temp/sq-process1996432278901624798properties
2017.10.16 21:43:25 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is up
2017.10.16 21:43:25 INFO  app[][o.s.a.p.JavaProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[web]: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonarqube/temp -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/server/*:/opt/sonarqube/lib/jdbc/mysql/mysql-connector-java-5.1.42.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer /opt/sonarqube/temp/sq-process4593096976787055653properties
2017.10.16 21:43:37 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [web] is stopped
2017.10.16 21:43:37 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [es] is stopped
2017.10.16 21:43:37 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
<-- Wrapper Stopped
```

I also tried to setup `sonar.log.level=DEBUG` into `conf/sonar.properties` but I don't get any additional log messages.

My JDK seems to be good:

```
root@dev:/opt/sonarqube# java -version
java version "1.8.0_144"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_144-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.144-b01, mixed mode)
```

Could you help me please?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

This is what I see into `/opt/sonarqube/logs/web.log`:

```
2017.10.16 21:49:23 WARN  web[][o.a.c.l.WebappClassLoaderBase] The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [elasticsearch[Suicide][transport_client_timer][T#1]{Hashed wheel timer #1}] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
 org.jboss.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$Worker.waitForNextTick(HashedWheelTimer.java:445)
 org.jboss.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$Worker.run(HashedWheelTimer.java:364)
 org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2017.10.16 21:49:23 WARN  web[][o.a.c.l.WebappClassLoaderBase] The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [elasticsearch[Suicide][generic][T#1]] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
 java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:460)
 java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:362)
 java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:941)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1073)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2017.10.16 21:49:23 WARN  web[][o.a.c.l.WebappClassLoaderBase] The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [Timer-0] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:552)
 java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
2017.10.16 21:49:23 DEBUG web[][o.s.s.a.TomcatAccessLog] Tomcat is started
2017.10.16 21:49:23 INFO  web[][o.s.s.a.EmbeddedTomcat] HTTP connector enabled on port 9000
2017.10.16 21:49:23 DEBUG web[][o.s.s.a.TomcatAccessLog] Tomcat is stopped
```

**EDIT 2:**

No tables are created into the MySQL database.

This is the database configuration into `sonar.properties`:

```
sonar.jdbc.username=sonarqube
sonar.jdbc.password=[password]
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://[mysql IP address]:3306/sonarqube?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useConfigs=maxPerformance&useSSL=false
```

I checked username and password and I can correctly connect to the database using `mysql -H[mysql IP address] -usonarqube -p sonarqube`

Comment: Check _$SONARQUBE_HOME/logs/web.log_. You should see something relevant there.

Comment: And in the other logs in that directory?

Comment: Ok, I found the problem: "Web server startup failed: Unsupported mysql version: 5.5. Minimal supported version is 5.6." I am using MariaDB 10.0.17 on production. Isn't any way to use this version?

Comment: I also tried installing MariaDB 10.2 (the latest stable), same error. MariaDB is the default on Debian 9, how we can solve?